# Why did dd report a "No Space" error after cloning a USB drive?

Tags: dd, clone, usb-flash-drive, gpt, usb-boot

In Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, I use this command to clone one [Samsung USB GPT drive](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07BPKKTGL) to another identical drive:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/sdb of=/dev/sdc bs=16M conv=sync,noerror status=progress
```

This operation concludes with the following statements:

```
256590741504 bytes (257 GB, 239 GiB) copied, 2555 s, 100 MB/s
dd: error writing '/dev/sdc': No space left on device
15297+1 records in
15927+0 records out
256641603584 bytes (257 GB, 239 GiB) copied, 2614.36 s, 98.2 MB/s
```

The question is, why did `dd` report an error? If I'm not repeating myself, why did the second "bytes copied" statement cite a larger value than the first?

The source drive is [a bootable pseudo-WTG](https://raywoodcockslatest.wordpress.com/2023/08/22/wtg-update/) (Windows To Go) drive. That is, it runs Windows 10. Its partitions (with labels, total sizes, and flags, as reported by GParted) are as follows:

```
NTFS  (no label) 518.34 MiB diag
FAT32 ESP         91.02 MiB boot,esp
NTFS  PROGRAM    238.42 GiB msftdata
```

Upon completion of the `dd` command, [`lsblk -ba`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/565797/list-size-of-all-disks-and-partitions-in-bytes) reports that the drives, and their respective partitions, are exactly the same sizes. This time, both source and target drives boot successfully. In a previous try on a different computer, as I recall, the resulting target drive did not boot successfully.

Comment: are the drives an **exact** multiple of 16Megabytes? remove `sync` from `conv=sync` and the error will probably go away (it's a pointless option anyway for this use case)

Comment: @JaromandaX : `lsblk -ba` reports that these Samsung Bar Plus 256GB (MUF-256BE3/AM) USB 3.1 drives contain 256,641,603,584 bytes. Not exactly divisible by 1 MB nor by 1 MiB. But apparently that's moot - removing `sync` did eliminate the error. Thanks!

Comment: it's not moot, it's the reason for the warning message